# Can a single visual contain fields from 2 separate datasets in Quicksight?

Tags: dataset, amazon-quicksight

[image: A bar chart in Quicksight]

The example above is where I'd like to have **X axis** coming from **dataset_1**, and **Value** coming from **dataset_2**.

In PowerBI and QlikSense, this is possible because 2 tables can be related via key fields without being joined.

But it seems in Quicksight, the visual is linked to a single dataset. When I change to a different dataset, the selection automatically goes out of the visual.

Am I missing some steps or is it just not possible in Quicksight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QuickSight, all visuals can only make use of a single dataset. However, if you have an author/admin account, you should be able to create a new dataset joining data coming from existing datasets see [Creating dataset using existing datasets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/create-a-dataset-existing-dataset.html).

Alternatively you can create a new dataset and join the data coming from your datasource. See [Joining Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/joining-data.html)